# `and` condition in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I know how to config a "not match" condition in nginx:

```
if($request_uri !~ ^api/.*){
    rewrite $1/index.html break;
}
```

But how about if there is a requirement of `^static/.*`?

how to write the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like bellow:

```
if ($request_uri !~ "(^api/.*)|(^static/.*)"){
    rewrite $1/index.html break;
}
```

Or a hard method:

```
set $num 0;
if($request_uri !~ ^api/.* ){
    set $num 1;
}

if($request_uri !~ ^static/.*){
    set $num 1$num;
}

if ($num = 11) {
    rewrite $1/index.html break;
}
```